# Magento 2 QuickSearch widget

Tags: magento2, jquery, widgets, autocomplete

Does anyone have any experience with Magento 2 [QuickSearch widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_quickSearch.html) so perhaps they **can provide a code sample (how to use it in module)**? I have managed to include it to my js file, but i can not figure out **how to provide the data what the widget should use for autocomplete**?

As much as i have understood it is something similar to jQuery-ui autocomplete? I am trying to write a module that adds custom block to checkout with autocomplete field.

*Additional question: (Also from documentation I can see that it is possible set `minSearchLength`(`minLength` in jQuery), but what about jQuery `delay`?)*